# Remove duplicate from URL-string with PHP

Tags: php, duplicates

My current code in PHP:

```
$str = "https://app.abc.com/mlk//mlk/List_xyz?loginname=0&project=0&company=a&phase=0&type=0&kind=need_to_check"
$output = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $str)));
print $output
```

But it results in the wrong output.

My desired output is `"https://app.abc.com/mlk/List_xyz?loginname=0&project=0&company=a&phase=0&type=0&kind=need_to_check"`

How can I remove the duplicated text, for example `/mlk/` in my above string?

Note: The duplicate is not always `/mlk/`. Sometimes it is `/example/` or similar.

For example, `/a/b/b/a/c/b/` must become `/a/b/c/`

Comment: How to you define duplication here : similar consecutive subpaths, or `/a/b/b/a/c/b/` must become `/a/b/c/` ?

Comment: This mode is correct: /a/b/b/a/c/b/ must become /a/b/c/ . thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the functions [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is the character on which you will split the string. As there isn't any comma in your URL, your `explode(',', $str)` doesn't have any effect: it returns an array of one element, the full URL.

You need to explode the string on the character `/`.

Then, same behavior for [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$str = "https://app.abc.com//a/b/b/a/c/b//List_xyz?loginname=0&project=0&company=a&phase=0&type=0&kind=need_to_check";
$output = implode('/', array_unique(explode('/', $str)));
print $output;
```

Output:

```
https://app.abc.com/a/b/c/List_xyz?loginname=0&project=0&company=a&phase=0&type=0&kind=need_to_check
```